# How to use parallel async in meteor

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

I am having three functions to fetch screenshots, yelp and google data of a website.The result of these three functions are pushed to an array of subdocuments which will get inserted to database.I need to increase the performance of this api.Is it possible to call these functions using parallel async in meteor without using npm module?
The line of code I used is shown below

```
 Meteor.methods({
   insertApart : function(apart){
     var google_data = setGoogleData(apart);
     var screen_captures_data = setScreenShots(apart);
     var yelp_data = setYelpData(apart); 

     function setGoogleData(apart) {
        // code to fetch google data
     }

     function setScreenShots(apart) {
        // code to fetch screen shots
     }

     function setYelpData(apart) {
        // code to fetch yelp data
     }

     var data=[];
     data.google = google_data;// setting google data
     data.screen_captures = screen_captures_data;// setting screen captures
     data.yelp = yelp_data;// setting yelp data
     var id = Apartments.insert(data);
     return id;
  }
});
```

Comment: Wrap each call in a setTimout 0 block? Or put the code into 3 meteor methods and use this.unblock. I'm not sure this will work but worth a try

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock: I am getting a null array when I use setTimeout 0, also it should be done inside one meteor method. Is there any other method?

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense. That's the async happening. How are you Fetching the google and yelp data? If it uses callbacks, then you can run all 3 calls in parallel. But you'd have to work out a way to only insert the document once all 3 methods have completed

Comment: Use `Meteor.wrapAsync` instead to wrap each function in its own Fiber. Fibers are Meteors way of handling asynchronous functions and lets you call the function in a synchronous manner.

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock: I am not using any callbacks in this method

Comment: @Svenskunganka: I cannot use fibers, as it is a npm module.I need parallel execution of the three functions, and I think this couldnot be done using Meteor.wrapAsync

Comment: Fibers are installed in Meteor by default. The entire Meteor core uses it. `Meteor.wrapAsync` method wraps your function in a firber.

Comment: @Svenskunganka: By using Meteor.wrapAsync, will it increase the performance? The function to fetch google and yelp data is a little bit slow

Comment: Completely depends on what your functions does. If they are blocking (e.g waiting for response from API's, etc), you will see good performance increase when you wrap them in their own fibers, but if they are doing computation-heavy tasks you will have to optimize them instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92387/discussion-between-pooja-jayaraj-and-svenskunganka).

Comment: Guessing it's mostly just waiting for Google and yelp to respond. Not heavy computation.